# In Visual Basic, how can I force a newline in a textbox after wordwrap?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, word-wrap

In Visual Basic, when typing in a multilines textbox (WordWrap = true) and when reaching the end of the (width) textbox, it automatically forces a new line. However, it looks like it did add (vbNewLine). But that's not the case.

How do I force vbNewLine when wordwrap have been reached? In a simple why.

Comment: Of course that's not the case.  The whole point is that the control wraps the text where required to show it all without affecting the text itself.  If it did affect the text then it couldn't reflow automatically if and when the `TextBox` was resized.  I don't have the specific code to insert a line break and I'm not about to work it out for you but you should look at the `GetLineFromCharIndex` method.  It will enable you to determine when the text has wrapped to the next line.  If you make a genuine attempt and it doesn't work, then we can talk further.

Comment: The whole point of enabling wordwrap is to **not** require a newline at the end of each line, but to have the text automatically wrap to the size of the edit control. If you don't want that behavior, turn off wordwrap.

Comment: Of course, you should already know about that `GetLineFromCharIndex` method because the very first thing you should have done when you wanted help doing something with a `TextBox` is opened the Help documentation for the `TextBox` class and taken a look at what members it has and what they do.  That's exactly how I know about that method.

Comment: This a common question and no one have an answer for it. I understand what is it made for, they should've  add an option to force newline when it wraps.

Comment: I think it should. And i love it how people comment, i could do it but i don't want to. Everytime i read a question. And love it when people comment as senseless question. As the the question too dumb for you, not understanding what we need it for. If you don't have an answer or don't want to answer. Why are you here. I'll find it and will post the answer for the people who needs it.

Comment: If you think there is a right and wrong in programming, you'll never get anywhere in life. You'll always be an employee waiting for the protocol to be handed to you. There is something called GET THE JOB DONE no matter what. That's why there are programmers have the knowledge to create anything, but they never do. Because they're stuck in protocols that was created by regular people. Its funny, no one has an answer. Yet people have the time to comment. If you don't want to answer please don't comment. Just move on. Its my question i'll answer it. And Keep up the good work.

Comment: Measure text length (and I don't mean character length with text.length) then insert the newline where you need (based on your textbox width).

Comment: If you want to add your own new line characters, i would suggest using a `RichTextBox` instead

Comment: Commenting on an old post , the struggle I had trying to get help from Geekie bullies. I hardly use stackoverflow anymore. I must say, thank God to Chat GPT, I pay 20 dollars a month. I know now more than all these Geekie bullies combined. If you need help let me now lol.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned setting the `WordWrap` property I will assume that you are using the [Windows Forms TextBox control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.7.2).  This control is a wrapper around the native EDIT control.  The native control supports soft-line breaks that are inserted as two carriage returns and a line feed when the text wraps.

This feature can be enabled by sending the control the [EM_FMTLINES message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/em-fmtlines).

```
Const EM_FMTLINES As Int32 = &HC8
Const softLineBreak As String = ChrW(13) & ChrW(13) & ChrW(10)

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Boolean, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SendMessage(TextBox1.Handle, EM_FMTLINES, True, IntPtr.Zero)
End Sub
```

You could just replace the soft-line break character sequence with `Environment.Newline` to convert them to hard-line breaks.

```
Dim textWithHardBreaks As String = TextBox1.Text.Replace(softLineBreak, Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: You are a Genius. Thank you so much. You saved me alot of time. That's what stackoverflow is all about. Helping people save time, and share the knowledge. Keep up the good work. Its all about that one person that can make a difference. Thank you Again.

Comment: I've been looking for this for over a year. You made my day. Simply done. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Works With fixed width fonts

```
Private Function WordWrap(text As String, wrapLength As Integer) As String

    If text.Length > wrapLength Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0 'start on first line

        Dim Lines As New List(Of String)(text.Split(vbLf))
        Dim WrappedText As String = ""

        Do

            Lines(i) = Lines(i).Replace(vbCr, "")
            Lines(i) = Lines(i).Replace(vbLf, "")



            If Lines(i).Length > wrapLength Then   ' Need to split down the line

                Dim charposition As Integer = 0
                Dim Wordsfound = 0
                Dim inword As Boolean = False


                Dim wordstart As Integer = charposition
                Do
                    '' check for non printable character or space

                    If charposition = Lines(i).Length Or Char.IsControl(Lines(i), charposition) Or Lines(i).Chars(charposition) = Chr(32) Then
                        If inword = True Then          ' already in a word ?
                            Dim wordend As Integer = charposition - 1
                            'word start and end position is here
                            'need to check if word end position if over wrap boundary


                            inword = False
                            If wordend > wrapLength - 1 Then
                                If wordend - wordstart >= wrapLength Then

                                    ' word length is greater than wrap width - so its too big to wrap

                                Else

                                    'Word to be wrapped

                                    Lines.Insert(i + 1, Lines(i).Substring(wordstart, Lines(i).Count - wordstart))

                                    Lines(i) = Lines(i).Substring(0, wordstart)


                                End If


                            End If



                        End If



                    ElseIf inword = False Then

                        inword = True
                        Wordsfound = Wordsfound + 1
                        wordstart = charposition


                    End If

                    charposition = charposition + 1
                Loop While charposition < Lines(i).Length + 1




            Else


            End If

            i = i + 1   'increment to next line
        Loop While (i < Lines.Count)

        For Each item In Lines
            WrappedText = WrappedText & item.ToString & vbCrLf
        Next





        Return WrappedText + vbCrLf

    Else

        Return text + vbCrLf

    End If



End Function
```